# Bind previous value to input field while using common form for update and add

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am using common form for add and update data.
When I am click on edit form and change input field value,but then I close the form.

Then the previous value should be display in table not the updated as I have not clicked on update form.
Can someone provide the solution for this. thanx in advance.

Here is html

```
 <form [formGroup]="addEducationForm">
 <div class="form-group" *ngIf="educationObjectAccess.gpa !== 'none'">
                <label for="gpa">GPA</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="number" formControlName="gpa" class="form-control" [readonly]="educationObjectAccess.gpa === 'read'" [(ngModel)]="educationData.gpa"
                    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && education.gpa.errors && educationObjectAccess.gpa !== 'none'}" />
                <div *ngIf="submitted && education.gpa.errors" class="invalid-feedback error-msg">
                    <div *ngIf="education.gpa.errors.required">GPA is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
 </form>
```

[image: update form]

[image: after closing the form still value updated]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by self.

```
<form [formGroup]="addEducationForm">
 <div class="form-group" *ngIf="educationObjectAccess.gpa !== 'none'">
                <label for="gpa">GPA</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="number" formControlName="gpa" class="form-control" [readonly]="educationObjectAccess.gpa === 'read'" [(ngModel)]="educationData.gpa"
                    [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && education.gpa.errors && educationObjectAccess.gpa !== 'none'}" />
                <div *ngIf="submitted && education.gpa.errors" class="invalid-feedback error-msg">
                    <div *ngIf="education.gpa.errors.required">GPA is required</div>
                </div>
            </div>
 </form>
```

replace round brackets in ngModel as it acts as both input/output.
instead of **[(ngModel)]** write **[ngModel]**.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind the value to `ngModel` as this updates the model with each change which is not what you want.

I would suggest keeping a separate myFormValues object which you update only when the user explicitly presses your update button.

```js
onUpdate(): void{

  this.myFormValues = Object.assign( ...this.myFormValues, ...this.addEducationForm.value )

}
```